# render_to_string in sidekiq worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sidekiq, pdfkit

I'm trying to do some PDF generation in my app which processes some data and then creates the PDF of the result. I'm using PDFKit so need to simply create an HTML view which is fine if I'm in a controller, but I want to push the processing into a background thread with Sidekiq.

I had planned to use `render_to_string` but due to it being part of a Controller only, I can't use it in Sidekiq.

Is there some way I can do this? I'd like to try and stick with Sidekiq but if not then I guess I just have to do it all within the controller?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK I've gone for a different approach.

I've created an abstract controller that is being called directly from the worker class, as describe here http://www.whatastruggle.com/generating-pdfs-in-background

Thanks anyway

**Edit**

Seems the link is dead, so to sum up what worked:

Create a new controller, this will be the rendering controller

*rendering_controller.rb*

```
class RenderingController < AbstractController::Base
  include AbstractController::Rendering
  include ActionView::Layouts
  include AbstractController::Helpers
  include AbstractController::Translation
  include AbstractController::AssetPaths
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  include WickedPdf::PdfHelper

  self.view_paths = 'app/views'
end
```

Then wherever you need to use it

```
rc = RenderingController.new
rc.render_to_string(template: 'template/name', locals: { local: value })
```

Note this is no longer required if you're using Rails 5+ since they enabled rendering outside of controllers. Instead you can now just do:

```
ApplicationController.render :index
```

More details are available [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Renderer.html)

Comment: This URL just goes to a blank page. Is there a chance you still have it somewhere? I'm looking to do the same thing. Processing something in the background and wanting to send the results in a PDF to a user, but cannot access `render_to_string` from the worker.

Comment: @LewlSauce sorry, I don't have the page at all anymore, but I've updated the answer to include specifics on the solution. If you're using Rails 5+ however you can now do this out-the-box

Comment: In Rails 5 it's not `ApplicationController.render` but rather `ApplicationController.new.render`.

Answer (score 0):

Why couldn't you render_to_string in the controller, store the returned HTML in a variable, pass the HTML into a sidekiq job?

Comment: I could've, but the render_to_string method took quite a while to process and I wanted the request to return quickly rather than wait for it to generate the HTML. I wanted that to happen in the background